# A nonlinear first-order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do we solve the following differential equation?
$$(y{}')^{2}+p(x)(1+y^2)^{3}=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach.

Given:

$$(y')^{2}+p(x)(y^2+1)^{3}=0$$

We can solve for $y'$ by taking square roots, yielding:

$$y' = \pm ~ i ~ \sqrt{p(x)}~(y^2+1)^{3/2}$$

We can now separate and integrate:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{(y^2+1)^{3/2}}~ dy = \pm \int i ~ \sqrt{p(x)}~dx$$

Comment: Any suggestion for solving the integral on the LHS?

Comment: Substitute $y = \tan u, dy = \sec^2 u ~du$. This will get you to $\int \cos(u) du$, which is $\sin u + c$. Substitute and this will result in $\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}} + c$.

Comment: You are very welcome. Regards